# .net Framework, OWIN and getting JWT tokens

Tags: c#, jwt, owin

So I have a project making use of OWIN to issue JWT tokens to the front end.

When a user makes a delete request to the backend, and adds a header with the JWT token. How can you get the JWT payload to check the userID in the delete endpoint on the backend? To check the payload to make sure its not an unrelated user trying to delete something not linked to them. If that makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you've already set up UseJwtBearerAuthentication, so you just want to know how to read the current user from Owin? It's just User.Identity I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use built-in User property in Controller,which has User.Claims to get User's Id with the claim you've set in OWIN,or https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt library to decode the payload Claims from it. For checking your current JWT token,use https://jwt.io. It will show what claims do you have available and which one will you want to get.

Comment: Ok sweet, how would I get the JWT string? So in angular I have service.post(link,postobject,headerwithJWT); And in the back my endpoint only takes the object

Comment: Don't you send a JWT token? That token is the string you need.